# Optimize only a single method in a Debug configuration

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++

I would like to be able to compile one specific method as if the configuration for optimization was `/O2` for "Maximized Speed".

I have tried looking up for the `#pragma optimize("", { on, off })` solution, but it doesn't work.

```
#pragma optimize("", on)
void Mesh::openGL_paint()
{
    // external functions calls with huge overhead when debugging.
}
#pragma optimize("", off)
```

Comment: For portability I'd place that function in its own file (or in with a bunch of other files that require a similar optimization level) and handle it at the build system level with a rule that built .opt.o files or similar.

Comment: I believe you can use #pragma to disable optimisation for a function in a file that is compiled with optimisation enabled, but not the other way round.

Comment: @user4581301 make that a comment with more details so I can choose it as accepted answer. It works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulSanders: That's not strictly true, but it is the actual problem at hnad here.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include *which* optimization parameters you want to turn on. And since it's a debug build, there are no command-line defaults to fall back on.

`#pragma optimize("gty", on)`